# How can solve this partial differential equation (PDE) and plot?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, finite-difference-method

How can plot and solve this partial differential equation in mathematica?

$$
K \frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial x^2}- h (T-T_m) = \frac{\partial T}{\partial t}
$$

$ Tm = 25 $

$ k= 47 $

$ h= 1.5 $

this equation is for a bar 1 meter long the boundary conditions

$ T(0,t) = 0 °C $

$ T(L,t) = 0 °C $

And the initial conditions are

$ T(x,0) = 42 °C $

And how can solve whit the finite difference method?

I try with this

```
Ecuacion = D[\[Theta][x, s], x, x] - (h + s)/k \[Theta][x, s] == -(1/ s) (h Ta + 41)

SolED = DSolve[{Ecuacion, \[Theta][0, s] == 0, \[Theta][L, s] == 0}, \[Theta][x, s], x]
```

Comment: Could you please give us your `code` so that people can use it to answer your question.

Comment: Yes I put the code in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Clear[x, Ecuacion, s];

Ecuacion = D[\[Theta][x, s], {x,2}] == -(1/s) (h Ta + 41) + (h + s)/k \[Theta][x, s];
SolED    = DSolve[{Ecuacion, \[Theta][0, s] == 0, \[Theta][L, s] == 0}, \[Theta][x,s], x]
           //FullSimplify

(*
 The solution is:
    {{\[Theta][x, s] -> -((
        E^(-((Sqrt[h + s] x)/Sqrt[
          k])) (-1 + E^((Sqrt[h + s] x)/Sqrt[
           k])) (-E^(((L Sqrt[h + s])/Sqrt[k])) + E^((Sqrt[h + s] x)/Sqrt[
           k])) k (41 + h Ta))/((1 + E^((L Sqrt[h + s])/Sqrt[k])) s (h + 
           s)))}}
*)
```

Comment: Yes, but when I do the Laplace transfform dont give me a solution. thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Conan: Please post the `code` you applied so that I can try to answer.

Comment: the code is in my question, what I did was to use Laplace and solve the equation, once the equation was solved I used inverse transform in Mathematica to be able to return to the time domain. Thanks
 :)

Comment: I try to use this: 

     pde = 47* D[T[x, t], {x, 2}] - D[T[x, t], t] - 47*(T[x, t] - 25) == 0 
     S2 = NDSolve[{pde, T[0, t] == 0 , T[1.5, t] == 0, T[x, 0] == 42}, 
      T[x, t], {x, t}]

Comment: @Conan: You have a second order differential equation, therefore, you need to give the required first order initial values, otherwise, you system of ODEs will be undetermined. The reason is that the number of equations is less than the number of dependent variables.

Comment: So how am I raising the problem, it has no solution?